# New Shutdown Message with 20.04

Tags: shutdown, 20.04

I just upgraded to 20.04 and now see a terminal message when shutting down or restarting my system:

`[32.708998] ata2: failed stop FIS RX (-16)`

It will flash for a second. Sometimes there will be a duplicate line. Then my system will shutdown. I have not noticed any problems while running. Wondering if it is something that needs to be addressed. Thanks.

Ryzen 5 3600X
Nvidia RTX 2070S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to it might be worth it to file a bug report against `libahci` but it seems to be a minor issue. The [message](https://github.com/linuxkit/linux/blob/master/drivers/ata/libahci.c) (lines 919 and 724) is failing to "disable FIS reception" and [from Intel AHCI handling (5.2.4)](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/serial-ata-ahci-spec-rev095.pdf):

> If the FIS reception failed, non-fatal error handling is performed

Comment: I don't have an Intel processor, is it still the same issue?

Comment: yeah, it is ata / achi related. It is just that they have a paper on it ;)