# Shutdown msg: ata failed stop fis rx (-16)

Tags: shutdown, dmesg, sata

I am dual booting ubuntu 20.04/w10 on separate NVme.m2 on an asrock x570 and i have an ssd connected too as a storage drive. When i shutdown/restart my system, the following msg flashes for a sec:
**[32.227398] ata1: failed stop FIS RX (-16).**
Nothing seems to be affected,my system shuts down / restarts as intended. Running dmesg and filtering the log i found:

> [    1.387816] ahci 0000:0c:00.0: failed stop FIS RX (-16)

I tried to figure out what causes this but i can't seem to find an answer.
I am not that much experienced with linux and i'd really appreciate some help.
**EDIT:**
I found out that if i suspend-wakeup-shutdown then the message does not appear.
Smart data:
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend checking for firmware updates for the NVme and SSD.

Comment: What computer? Which processor... Intel or AMD?

Comment: Use the `Disks` app to get the **SMART Data** for both drives, and take a couple of screenshots.

Comment: amd ryzen 3700 / taichi x570 / rtx2070 super

Comment: Try setting **amd_iommu=off** as a kernel parameter. Source https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1858315#p1858315

Comment: To get the SMART Data in the `Disks` app, you have to go to the "hamburger" icon and select it there. Show me that SMART for all three NVme/SSDs.

Comment: @heynnema amd_iommu=off didn't work for me. after diggin around a bit i found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239925/new-shutdown-message-with-20-04

Comment: Go ahead and show me the SMART Data for all of the drives. Some SMART Data may require 2 screenshots, as the data window is scrollable.

Comment: @heynnema smart data is enabled only for my ssd and not the NVMEs.i 've edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for the SMART info. However, I don't know the answer to your question. Sorry.

Comment: no worries! thx for your effort!

Comment: Your last edit made me think of something... show me `sudo blkid | grep -i swap` and `sudo grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.